# Can't configure Glassfish for new JavaMail session

Tags: glassfish, jakarta-mail

When I go to Glassfish web console localhost 4848 and go to Resources JavaMail and hit the "new" button, I get this error class java.lang.RuntimeException I'm fairly new to Glassfish and am trying to follow the mail tutorials. Can anyone give me some advice on where to start? Thx in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

For any one struggling to do this via the Web Console and doesn't want to downgrade, just use the sub-command line option to create the mail session then continue on the web console to add additional properties.

`asadmin> create-javamail-resource --mailhost localhost 
--mailuser sample --fromaddress sample\@sun\.com mail/MyMailSession`

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21443) introduced in the GlassFish 4.1.1 release.  [GlassFish 4.1](https://glassfish.java.net/download-archive.html) should work.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I was able to get the email to work. The problem was that they had setup Exchange for an Anonymous user with no security (SMTP not SMTPS). However, I never did get the JavaMail in Glassfish to work. Due to some other reasons, the decision was made to stick with the current version of Glassfish. I did try to go back to 4.1 as noted, but had similar issues in getting JavaMail setup as a Resource. Once I got the basic issue resolved, I abandoned the effort to go back to 4.1, so I'm not sure if that would have changed anything. 
Thx